# explorer.exe doesn't open correct folder when ran programmatically inside WSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to open `explorer.exe` from a Node.js script running inside WSL Ubuntu 20.04. The issue I've encountered is that `explorer.exe` never opens the folder I'd like it to. Instead of WSL user's home directory it opens my Windows user's `Documents` folder. What should I do to make `explorer.exe` open the folder I want?

Here's what I've tried:

The script first defines a function `execShellCommand` that promisifies `exec`. Then self-executing function first converts `process.env.HOME` to a Windows path with `wslpath`. Then it executes `explorer.exe` with the converted path as a parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/node

const execShellCommand = async cmd => {
  const exec = require('child_process').exec
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.warn(error)
      }
      resolve(stderr ? stderr : stdout)
    })
  })
}

;(async () => {
  const path = await execShellCommand(`wslpath -w "${process.env.HOME}"`)
  console.log({ path })
  await execShellCommand(`explorer.exe ${path}`)
})()
```

The output I get when I run my script in WSL

```
$ ./script.js 
{ path: '\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\user\n' }
Error: Command failed: explorer.exe \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\user


    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'explorer.exe \\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\user\n'
}
```

`explorer.exe` does run regardless of the error shown in the output. The weird part is that if I run the same command my script tries to run (`explorer.exe \\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\user\n`) directly in WSL terminal `explorer.exe` does open the folder I want it to. Trimming the new line at the end of the path doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do some additional escaping on the backslashes that are produced by `wslpath`.  The code below works for me, meaning ***it opens the correct directory in Windows Explorer***.

*Note: it does still throw the error you mentioned, which I think is due to the way node exits rather than anything wrong w/the execution of `explorer.exe`; I'm not a node expert by any stretch.*

```
#!/usr/bin/node

const execShellCommand = async cmd => {
          const exec = require('child_process').exec
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                      exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                                    if (error) {
                                                    console.warn(error)
                                                  }
                                    resolve(stderr ? stderr : stdout)
                                  })
                    })
}

;(async () => {
          let path = await execShellCommand(`wslpath -w "${process.env.HOME}"`)
          console.log("before", {path});
          path = path.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
          console.log("after", {path});
          await execShellCommand(`explorer.exe ${path}`)

})()
```

Even cleaner than replacing backslashes, I think this will work for you by resolving the `$HOME` variable directly into your command line:

```
await execShellCommand(`explorer.exe "$(wslpath -w $HOME)"`);
```